# Javascript: Onkeydown, move the text to a certain direction but needs to be pressed twice

Tags: javascript

In this code, for some reason I need to double press the key so that the text would go to the direction I want. If I don't do that the text will keep on going to the previous direction it went in. I was looking for a solution for this for 2 hours now, I seem to not be able to find the right code to place.

Here's the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/MindZeroJ5/4cykaLs8/

**HTML**:

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid black;" width="500" height="500" ></canvas>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
"use strict";
var c = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    y,
    x,
    kpd,
    kcd,
    kpu,
    kcu,
    HEIGHT,
    WIDTH;

x = 50;
y = 50;
HEIGHT = 500;
WIDTH = 500;

ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("Hello World!", x, y);

function movetextup() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    y -= 10;
    ctx.fillText("Hello World!", x, y);
    console.log(x + " " + y);
}
function movetextdown() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    y += 10;
    ctx.fillText("Hello World!", x, y);
    console.log(x + " " + y);
}
function movetextleft() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    x -= 10;
    ctx.fillText("Hello World!", x, y);
    console.log(x + " " + y);
}
function movetextright() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    x += 10;
    ctx.fillText("Hello World!", x, y);
    console.log(x + " " + y);
}

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    kpd = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    kcd = e.keyCode;
    console.log('pressed ' + kpd);
    if (kpu == "W") {
        movetextup();
    }
    if (kpu == "S") {
        movetextdown();
    }
    if (kpu == "A") {
        movetextleft();
    }
    if (kpu == "D") {
        movetextright();
    }
};
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    kpu = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    kcu = e.keyCode;
    console.log('unpressed ' + kpu);
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are overwriting the global variable that holds the direction on the "keyup", so if you're moving to the left (`D`), and then press `A` (to go to right), the "keyup" even will set the direction (`kpu`) to `D`, only when you press again it will be set to `A`.
My recommendation is to use only the `onkeydown` event, and set the direction there, that way you won't have conflict of events overwriting the same variable with different values:
https://jsfiddle.net/0d8ue6po/

Note that in your example, you don't even need a global variable (not sure what you'll do in the future with it), but you could just do:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  var kpu = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  var kcd = e.keyCode;
  /* rest of the code for moving */
}
```

That way you wouldn't have the overwriting problem either.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're using wrong variable when checking keycode onkeydown, use `kpd` instead of `kpu`, i've updated your [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cykaLs8/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You are using keyup event result (**kpu**) in keydown event handler which means that a key should be made down and up and down again in order to hit the correct key value.

Well, in your case it seems that there is no need for keyup event handler, hence you had better use **kpd** variable in your keydown event handler to dispatch the key event user sends.